# Why does $\int xf(x) \neq 0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Using integration by parts we get that this is equal to
$$x \int f(x)dx - \int \left(\int f(x) dx\right)dx$$

I thought that this is the same as

$$x \int f(x)dx - \int 1 dx\int f(x) dx$$

which is the same as

$$x \int f(x) dx - x \int f(x) dx$$

However computing the definite integral with $f(x) = e^x$ from $0$ to $1$ gives $1$.

Which step is wrong? I am assuming it is the step where I separate the double integral into the product of two integrals but I am not sure how else to compute the double integral. For example the function I am working with is $f(x) = 1$ if $x>0.5$ and $f(x)=0 $ otherwise and I am computing the definite integral from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: $\int (\int f(x)\ dx)\ dx \ne (\int\ dx)(\int f(x)\ dx)$

Comment: I think your comment is potentially misleading. While what you wrote is true for indefinite integrals it is true for definite integrals over the same range. So if someone like myself was trying to solve a definite integral of this form they would get 0 unless they noticed what Alan pointed out below that the inner integral is indefinite even when the outer integral is definite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrating by parts, say on $[a,b]$, you'll get 
$$
\int\limits_a^b xf(x)dx = \left.x\left(\int\limits_a^x f(t)dt+ C\right)\right|^b_a - \int\limits_a^b \left(\int\limits_a^x f(t) dt +C\right)dx 
$$
The inner integral that you wrote is a primitive for $f$, not a number.

Comment: I see. You are saying the inner integral in the second term is indefinite?

Comment: Yes, an indefinite integral.

Comment: What happens to the constant of integration from the indefinite integral? I am still unsure how to solve this analytically even for the simple example I gave i.e.  Integrating from 0 to 1 $f(x) = 1$ if $x>0.5$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise.

Comment: That was my fault :) For your example you can break the integral as $\int\limits_0^1 xf(x)dx = \int\limits_0^{0.5} xf(x)dx+\int\limits_{0.5}^1 xf(x)dx$ and $f$ is constant in both intervals.

Comment: Oh Duh not sure how I missed that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid confusion I will use $u$ rather than $x$ for dummy and also $F(x)=\int^xf(u)du$.  $\int^xuf(u)du=xF(x)-\int^xF(u)du$.  This last term is not the same as $\int^x1duF(x)$, which is what you have.

Comment: Thanks. Why is the last term not the same as what I had? For example if we solve $\int^{x} f(u)du$ and get some constant k we now have $\int^{x} k du = k \int^{x} 1 du$ right?

Comment: @TPaul  The last term is$\int^x1(\int^uf(v)dv)du=\int^x 1F(u)du$.  You made it into two separate integrals.

Answer (score 0):

Call $F$ an antiderivative of $f$; thus integration by parts becomes
$$
\int xf(x)\,dx=xF(x)-\int F(x)\,dx
$$
Can you spot your false argument now?

Comment: I dont think my confusion stems from this step. My confusion was that even if the original integral is definite the inner integral, in your example $F(x)$ is indefinite.

Comment: @TPaul You don't have definite integrals in your question.

Answer (score 0):

When you are integrating a function f(x),

**$$\int(f(x)dx)= x*f(x) - \int(x*f’(x)dx) $$**

Where f’(x) is the derivative of f(x).

When integrating another time, you’ll have:

**$$\int xf(x).dx -\int \int xf’(x)dx dx $$**

Which is different than your second term, thus the equation you are calculating won’t be equal to 0.

If you want, I can solve it for you on the f(x) = e^x  example